# Cannot SSH to link-local IPv6 address on Packet Tracer

Tags: ssh, cisco, ipv6, link-local

due to the fact that I don't have physical equipment at the moment I don't know if what I am about to say is purely an issue with Packet Tracer.

I configured a Catalyst 2960 switch to allow for remote SSH connections.

```
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 ipv6 address FE80::2 link-local
 ipv6 address 2001:DB8:ACAD::2/64
 ipv6 enable
!
```

I also configured a computer with the IPv6 Address `2001:DB8:ACAD::3/64` and the link local address `FE80::1`.

I can access the switch just fine through the global unicast address by doing `ssh -L Admin01 2001:DB8:ACAD::2` in the virtual command prompt. I can also successfully ping the switch to the link local address by doing `ping FE80::2`. With all that said, I cannot SSH into the switch through the link local address.

```
C:\>ping FE80::2

Pinging FE80::2 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from FE80::2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255
Reply from FE80::2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=255

Ping statistics for FE80::2:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

Control-C
^C
C:\>ssh -L Admin01 FE80::2

% Connection timed out; remote host not responding
```

I am a bit new to networking, sorry if I missed out something obvious.

Comment: A link local address is a fallback when no other address is available, but in your case, you have assigned a global ipv6 address. My guess would be that the cisco switch always prefers to use this address if available, and therefore the tcp connection only works with the global ipv6 address.

Comment: Tried only assigning a link local address to the switch. It still replies to pings but not to SSH.